# Map $g:x\in X\longrightarrow (x,f(x))\in X\times Y$ is an embedding

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be Hausdorff and locally euclidean spaces, $f:x\in X \rightarrow f(x)\in Y$ a continuous function. Is the map $g:x\in X\longrightarrow (x,f(x))\in X\times Y$ is an embedding?

I can prove that $g$ is inyective and continuous. However, I struggle proving that it is an open map.

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is a homeomorphism with its image, for all spaces $X,Y$, as the projection is the continuous inverse. Hence an embedding. No conditions on $X$ or $Y$ are needed, only continuity of $f$.

Comment: I don't understand "the projection is the continuous inverse"

Comment: The function $p: X \times Y \rightarrow X$ defined by $p(x,y)=x$ is continuous and the inverse map.